# What conditions can cause clock() to return -1 (ie fail)?

Tags: c++, time, clock

I'm using clock() from time.h to provide a rough time elapsed mechanism for an operation I want performed around once per second.  (I probably want to use time() but the majority of the question stands since time() also returns -1 on a failure).  It's not critical to be precise since other thresholds are high enough that if this were out even up to a half second, it'd be ok.

The function returns -1 on a failure, and at present if I detect a failure I retry the clock up to 100 times over the next second.

Other than some sort of physical hardware failure, what reasons can cause clock() or time() to fail?  If after the retries it is still -1, can I assume that the system is having a "bigger problem" (and so I may want to gracefully exit)?

Comment: It's a long shot, but does the value of `errno` contain anything useful after `clock` returns `-1`?

Comment: a bug in the os? a bug in the library implementing a wrapper around the OS? in the case of a realtime system the inability to fullfill the request in the configured time. missing capabilities to use the clock configured in the OS for clock(). too many subsequent calls to clock() for OSs where this is a failure. and I think I can come up with esotheric ones. Is your real question maybe whether you need to really care about it failing?

Comment: @PlasmaHH If you convert that to an answer I can at least upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [friendly man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/clock.html) states the following:

> If the processor time used is not available or its value cannot be
> represented, the function shall return the value (clock_t)-1

Do note that `clock()` returns a value based on CPU time usage (on everything excluding Windows), if you want a wall clock time use `time()` instead.

Comment: And depending on the system, the `cannot be represented` clause might not apply.  On 32-bit Linux, for example, `clock_t` wraps around.  Note that the returned value could in principle happen to be `(clock_t)-1` if you call it at just the right moment, though I don't think that can actually happen on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From `man clock(3)`

> If the processor time used is not available or its value cannot be
>   represented, the function returns the value `(clock_t)-1`

Sounds like a conformant implement could just return that and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function from a kernel mode application can also cause it to fail, which was what I was concerned about.